# Need to pass a parameter on the onclick event of a button I add to my page using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a javascript that I include on some of my pages that will create a button on any contacts that are listed on the page.  The point of the button is to make it easy for the user to email that contact and that email will include information such as the site URL.

I include my function call using the following include

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-Subject="Site" src="../SiteAssets/js-test/AddContactButtons.js"></script>
```

My AddContactButtons.js has the following source:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Get the subject type
    var this_js_script = $('script[src*=AddContactButtons]');
    var subjectType = this_js_script.attr('data-Subject'); 
    if (typeof subjectType == 'undefined' || subjectType == null || subjectType == ''){
      subjectType = "Site";
    }
    //console.log('subjectType='+subjectType);
    addContactButtons(subjectType);
});
function addContactButtons(subjectType){
    var listTitle="Contacts";
    console.log('addcontactButtons:subjectType='+subjectType);
    $("table.ms-listviewtable[summary='"+listTitle+"']>tbody>tr").each(function(){
        $(this).append("<input type='button' value='Help' style='background-color:#0072C5; color:white' class='btnSub' onclick='javascript:openMail(this);'>");
    });
}
function openMail(btn){
    var emailString = "mailto:";
    var emailID = $(btn).prev("td").text()
    //console.log(emailID);
    console.log('openMail:subjectType='+subjectType);

    emailString += emailID ;
    emailString += "?Subject=SharePoint Site Support - Site=";
    emailString += _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;;
    //alert(emailString);
    location.href=emailString;
}
```

The problem is I have tried a lot of different variations and can not seem to get the variable subjectType to my openMail function.  Ideally, I'd like to support the default which is site support subject, but I need options to send in a custom subject or at least some other variation that tells the person getting the email that it is for supporting a custom list (app).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: What does `console.log('openMail:subjectType='+subjectType);` print out? subjectType is undefined here, right?

Comment: Hi Steve, the way you've structured your code is complex, however I would invite you to try to run your code and trying to solve the errors that the console throws. There's a lof context issues, for example in the openMail function subjectType is not undefined.

Comment: Yes, it is undefined.  It's complex because I'm trying to provide easy ways for owners to add functionality and to hide the code from the owners.  In addition, the concept of re-use.

Comment: I suggest you pass subjectType explicitly to  openMail. `function openMail(btn, subjectType){...}` . and change the onclick event handler to `onclick='javascript:openMail(this, subjectType)`.  The reason is `subjectType` can not be captured in openMail from addContactButtons, no closure here. So, you need pass explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**: Create a global variable "subjectType" to achieve it. Modify the code as below.

```
var subjectType="";
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Get the subject type
    var this_js_script = $('script[src*=AddContactButtons]');
    subjectType = this_js_script.attr('data-Subject'); 
    if (typeof subjectType == 'undefined' || subjectType == null || subjectType == ''){
      subjectType = "Site";
    }
    //console.log('subjectType='+subjectType);
    addContactButtons(subjectType);
});
function addContactButtons(subjectType){
    var listTitle="Contacts";
    console.log('addcontactButtons:subjectType='+subjectType);
    $("table.ms-listviewtable[summary='"+listTitle+"']>tbody>tr").each(function(){
        $(this).append("<input type='button' value='Help' style='background-color:#0072C5; color:white' class='btnSub' onclick='javascript:openMail(this);'>");
    });
}
function openMail(btn){
    var emailString = "mailto:";
    var emailID = $(btn).prev("td").text()
    //console.log(emailID);
    console.log('openMail:subjectType='+subjectType);

    emailString += emailID ;
    emailString += "?Subject=SharePoint Site Support - Site=";
    emailString += _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;;
    //alert(emailString);
    location.href=emailString;
}
```

**Option 2**: Using jQuery code to achieve the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Get the subject type
    var this_js_script = $('script[src*=AddContactButtons]');
    var subjectType = this_js_script.attr('data-Subject'); 
    if (typeof subjectType == 'undefined' || subjectType == null || subjectType == ''){
      subjectType = "Site";
    }
    //console.log('subjectType='+subjectType);
    addContactButtons(subjectType);
});
function addContactButtons(subjectType){
    var listTitle="Contacts";
    console.log('addcontactButtons:subjectType='+subjectType);
    $("table.ms-listviewtable[summary='"+listTitle+"']>tbody>tr").each(function(){       
        $(this).append("<input type='button' value='Help' style='background-color:#0072C5; color:white' class='btnSub'>");
    });
    $("table.ms-listviewtable[summary='"+listTitle+"']>tbody>tr input[value='Help']").click(function(){
        openMail($(this),subjectType);
    });
}
function openMail(btn,subjectType){
    var emailString = "mailto:";
    var emailID = $(btn).prev("td").text()
    //console.log(emailID);
    console.log('openMail:subjectType='+subjectType);

    emailString += emailID ;
    emailString += "?Subject=SharePoint Site Support - Site=";
    emailString += _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;;
    //alert(emailString);
    location.href=emailString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a `click` handler to the button instead of using the `onclick` attribute so that you can explicitly pass in required parameters.

That is:

```
const button = $("<input type='button' value='Help' style='background-color:#0072C5; color:white' class='btnSub'>");
button.click(() => openMail(button, subjectType));
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Get the subject type
    var this_js_script = $('script[src*=AddContactButtons]');
    var subjectType = this_js_script.attr('data-Subject'); 
    if (typeof subjectType == 'undefined' || subjectType == null || subjectType == ''){
      subjectType = "Site";
    }
    //console.log('subjectType='+subjectType);
    addContactButtons(subjectType);
});
function addContactButtons(subjectType){
    var listTitle="Contacts";
    console.log('addcontactButtons:subjectType='+subjectType);
    $(".container").each(function(){
      const button = $("<input type='button' value='Help' style='background-color:#0072C5; color:white' class='btnSub'>");
      button.click(() => openMail(button, subjectType));
      $(this).append(button);
    });
}
function openMail(btn, subjectType){
  console.log('openMail:subjectType='+subjectType);
  /*
  var emailString = "mailto:";
  var emailID = $(btn).prev("td").text()
  //console.log(emailID);
  console.log('openMail:subjectType='+subjectType);

  emailString += emailID ;
  emailString += "?Subject=SharePoint Site Support - Site=";
  emailString += _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;;
  //alert(emailString);
  location.href=emailString;
  */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" data-Subject="Site" src="../SiteAssets/js-test/AddContactButtons.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

As @Bavo says, there is a scoping and context issue with what you've currently implemented.